# Unable to make mutable array iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary

I am new to iOS,

I am storing array of dictionary in `NSUserDefaults`,

What I want to do is now edit the array of dictionary stored in `NSUserDefaults`.

Here is the code I have written but it crashes on this line

```
[array[0] setObject:updateMonth forKey:@"Month"];
```

and says:

> **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary
>   setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object**

Code snippet:

**Storing:**

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"MONTHLY_BUDGET"];
```

and my data is

```
(
     {
        Amount = 1;
        Month = "July 2017";
        isMonthlySet = 1;
     }
   )
```

**Retriving:**

```
        array = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MONTHLY_BUDGET"] mutableCopy];

        NSString *updateMonth = @"ABCD";

        [array[0] setObject:updateMonth forKey:@"Month"];
```

Please help and why it is not working?

Comment: Your array is mutable but not Dictionary , and you are modifying dictionary value

Comment: add more code for understand . add storing and retrieving code .

Comment: simply replace this :         [array setObject:updateMonth forKey:@"Month"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
    [[array[0] mutableCopy] setObject:updateMonth forKey:@"Month"];
```

You are doing correct with array

```
    array = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MONTHLY_BUDGET"] mutableCopy];
```

But array contains `NSDictionary` not `NSMutableDictionary` so you required to use `mutableCopy`

Hope it is clear to you

**EDIT**

You should use readable code make you easy to change in future

use below code

```
NSMutableArray *array =  [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MONTHLY_BUDGET"] mutableCopy];

NSMutableDictionary *dictData = [array[0] mutableCopy]
// Set value 

[dictData setObject:updateMonth forKey:@"Month"];
```

// Assign to array back

```
 [array replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:dictData]

 Change UserDefault

  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[array copy] forKey:@"MONTHLY_BUDGET"];
```

Comment: thanx for the help it's working app is not getting crashed but value of updateMonth is not getting set :(

Comment: Amazing answer men it works.... i really understood my mistake but do i need to write `[array copy]` while setting object ?